# Structuring a URL to display all results for scraping data

Tags: php, xml, web-scraping

I am a GIS student working on a project focused on mapping unstructured data, in which I wrote a php script to scrape the following page that displays search results for US GIS job postings, to export to xml, geocode and map.

http://gisjobs.com/search_results_jobs/?action=search&listing_type%5Bequal%5D=Job&keywords%5Blike%5D=&Country%5Bmulti_like%5D%5B%5D=United+States&State%5Bmulti_like%5D%5B%5D=&City%5Blike%5D=&Salary%5Bnot_less%5D=&Salary%5Bnot_more%5D=&SalaryType%5Bmulti_like%5D%5B%5D=

However the results page defaults to 10 results per page. You can change the results to display 100 results post search, enough to cover all the results by scraping one page. But when you change to display 100 results, the URL changes to this:

http://gisjobs.com/search_results_jobs/?listings_per_page=100&restore=&page=1

which brings up an empty query when called from php. Is there a way to structure the URL to display all results (up to 100), so that only one page needs to be scraped?

(Adding &listings_per_page=100 to the end of the first URL doesn't work)

Comment: Now that I think of it, this should actually be on stackoverflow, you will probably get better answers than mine also.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work:

`http://gisjobs.com/search_results_jobs/?action=search&listing_type[equal]=Job&keywords[like]=&Country[multi_like][]=United+States&State[multi_like][]=&City[like]=&Salary[not_less]=&Salary[not_more]=&listings_per_page=100&SalaryType[multi_like][]=`

You just needed to append the attribute `&listings_per_page=100` to your query. This should work similar for other API's like this.

It looks like the most results you can return is 36 unless they have a format attribute where you can specify html, json or xml. Your best bet is to scrape the first page and use the next link and keep crawling till you get the 100 job listings you required.